# How to verify that $Ax =3x $ is a subspace of $R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. Verify that

$V= \{x \in R^n: Ax=3x\}$ is a subspace of $R^n$

I know I need to check the three conditions:

1. It contains the zero vector
2. It is closed under addition
3. It is closed under scalar multiplication

But I don't know where to start. I find subspaces really confusing!

Comment: Have you tried any of the three conditions? Can you prove that $0 \in V$, for instance?

Comment: Maybe writing it in the form $V = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : (A-3I)x = 0 \}$ will help you to see it!

Comment: You have three conditions to check. "Where to start" is with one of those conditions. Then another. And finally the last. You can choose the order yourself.

Comment: Do you know the null space of a matrix (or the kernel of a  linear map) is a subspace?

Answer (score 3):

1) $0\in V$ because $A0=0=3\cdot0$

2) Closure under addition means that if $u,v\in V$ then $u+v\in V$. As $A(u+v)=Au+Av=3u+3v=3(u+v)$ we are done.

3) Closure under scalar multiplication means that if $v\in V$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}$, then $kv\in V$. $A(kv)=kAv=k3v=3(kv)$ and we are done.